# Configure uwsgi server for performance

Tags: django, performance, uwsgi

I am deploying a uwsgi server for a django app. Each request will have a latency around 2 seconds. I need to handle 100 QPS. On a 4 cores machines, how should I configure the number of processes and the number of threads? I tried to play with the values but I do not understand what I am doing.

Answer (score 8):

Go through the uWSGI [Things to know](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) page. 100 requests per second should be easily attainable with uWSGI.

Based on uWSGI behavior I've experienced, I would recommend that you start with only [processes](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#processes) and don't use any [threads](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#threads).  With both processes and threads we observed that there seemed to be an affinity to use threads over processes.  That resulted in a single process handling all requests until it's thread pool was fully occupied and only then were requests handled by the next process.  This resulted in poor utilization of resources as a single core was maxed out with all other idle.  Turning off threading resulted in a massive performance boost for our particular use model.

Your experience may be different. The uWSGI authors stress that there isn't any magic config combination- it's completely dependent on your particular use case.  You need benchmark your app against various configurations to find the sweet spot. Additionally, unless you're able to use benchmarks that perfectly model your actual production load, you'll want to continue to monitor performance and methodically tweak settings after you deploy.

From the Things to know page:

> There is no magic rule for setting the number of processes or threads
>   to use. It is very much application and system dependent. Simple math
>   like processes = 2 * cpucores will not be enough. You need to
>   experiment with various setups and be prepared to constantly monitor
>   your apps. [uwsgitop](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgitop) could be a great tool to find the best values.

Comment: Commenting on this old answer but, I am currently on this same journey, and I also noticed for our Django+uWSGI app that threading did almost nothing positive when tested in docker on up to 4 cores. At best, threading was as good as just setting processes/workers. At worst it hurt performance.